# Where can I find Julia Smith's translation of the Septuagint?

Tags: bible-translation, septuagint

Julia Smith writes in her preface to her translation of the Bible,

> I had studied Latin and Greek at school, and began by translating the
> Greek New Testament, and then the Septuagint, from which our Saviour
> quoted one or two texts which are not in the Hebrew Bible, and there
> is now said to be no Hebrew Bible extant so old as the Septuagint.

https://studybible.info/version/JuliaSmith

The Old Testament in the link above is translated from Hebrew, so I was wondering if her translation of the Septuagint has survived. If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

On the [Textus Receptus](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/1001001) website, Julia Smith's translation is listed on the right hand side column underneath Green's Literal Version.

So, you can look up any verse of the Old or New Testament and see that verse as Smith translated it.

The full text can also be read on [Biblehub](https://www.biblehub.com/slt/genesis/1.htm)

Comment: I checked both sites and the translation is from the Masoretic Text.

Comment: @7MessRobHackOpen I believe Julia Smith only ever wrote one translation, and that from the Septuagint. Could you please link to the information that states the translation (under her **specific** name) is from the Masoretic.

Comment: In both those links, her translation of Deuteronomy 32:43 reads "Rejoice ye nations with him, For he will raise up the blood of his servants, And he will turn back vengeance to his adversaries, And he will expiate for his land, his people."

Comment: Whereas the LXX reads something like "Rejoice, ye heavens, with him, and let all the angels of God worship him; rejoice ye Gentiles, with his people, and let all the sons of God strengthen themselves in him; for he will avenge the blood of his sons, and he will render vengeance, and recompense justice to his enemies, and will reward them that hate him; and the Lord shall purge the land of his people."

Comment: Compare also Hebrews 1:6 and the Dead Sea Scrolls

Comment: Wikipedia also says in reference to the sources of the Julia Smith translation "Masoretic Text, Textus Receptus" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_Bible_translations#Complete_Bibles

Comment: @7MessRobHackOpen There seems to be a problem, doesn't there ?

Comment: Yes, it seems like Julia Smith's translation of the Septuagint (mentioned in her preface) has either disappeared into nothingness or become really difficult to find. So I want to know: Does it still exist, and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I find Julia Smith's translation of the Septuagint?
>
> I was wondering if her translation of the Septuagint has survived. If so, where can I find it?

Since the published or printed book only contains the translation of the original Hebrew for its Old Testament, the only place to find the others, based on the Septuagint and the Vulgate, is the location of their original manuscripts; in this particular case:

> <sup>13</sup> This LXX, currently held by the [Connecticut Historical Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connecticut_Historical_Society), consists of 268 numbered, undated booklets. On 30 April 1846, Julia noted at the end of booklet 133 (Job), *Wrote the bible from the Septuagint as far as thru the 30<sup>th</sup> chapter of Job in one year*.

— **Athalya Brenner-Idan**, *A Feminist Companion to the Bible: Prophets and Daniel*, footnote to page [267](http://books.google.com/books?id=hEmvAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA267).